# Sending data from controller to directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My controller receives some data from the service which has to be sent to a directive further but my directive does not seem to receive it. The parameter which I am sending is "newId" in the below code.
The contoller receives the value as I have checked by setting and alert but the directive says undefined.

```
**Controller:**
indApp.controller('DropboxController',  ['$scope', function ($scope ) {

$scope.$on('handledrag', function() {

$scope.template = template;
$scope.newId = newfield.id;

});



}]);

**Directive:**
indApp.directive('droppable', function($compile) {

return {        
        restrict: "A",
         scope: {   template: "="   ,
         newId: "=" },                                      
        link: function(scope, element) 
        {

         // again we need the native object
         var el = element[0];
         var defaultProps = {};
          el.addEventListener( 'dragover', function(e) {
             if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
            return false;
             },
            false
            );

            el.addEventListener( 'drop',   function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();



        var droppedItem = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        alert(scope.newId);
element.append(($compile(template)(scope)));


    scope.$apply();
            return false;
            },
            false
            );

         }

}
});
```

Comment: How are you using the directive? Where is the variable newfield coming from? Perhaps your events are not being fired in the order you think they are?  Have you tried just putting a watch on scope.newId in your directive rather than have it inside a drop event listener?

Comment: If you see the "template" variable above, it is been send in the same way as "newId" and received inside the directive as expected. If it works for one parameter then it should also work for the other one? The sequence of events are like: 1) The service class calculates some parameters and broadcasts them. 2) The controller receives them 3) The parameter should be received in the directive further from the controller.